# KDE launcher opens .desktop files in kate

Tags: linux, kde, mime-types, xdg

Opening programs via the 'Application Launcher' menu, then selecting the program works.

Using the launcher generated on the panel, eg by right-clicking on an open program, then selecting 'Show A Launcher When Not Running' places a .desktop file which is opened with `kate`.

`xdg-mime query filetype /opt/kde/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop`

returns `text/plain`, as does the same command for

`/opt/kde/share/applications/org.kde.rekonq.desktop` etc.

`xdg-mime query default text/plain` then returns `org.kde.kate.desktop`, explaining why the files are being opened by `kate`.

Presumably the problem here is that the mimetype of the `*.desktop` files should be something other than `text/plain`. What should it be? Is there a simple way to check/find out/change these?

Note: KDE-5, Plasma-5, (C)LFS, source installs, etc. No package manager.

Comment: I don't have KDE-5 but KDE-4.1x. However, this shouldn't matter much here IMO. The xdg-mime command for a `.desktop` file returned me `application/x-desktop` as the mime type. So as the **Properties -> Application -> Mimetype** that can be accessed by right-clicking `.desktop` file and choosing **Properties**. (This also allows you to add this mimetype.)

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `update-mime-database` repeatedly, with `/opt/kde/share/mime`, `/opt/gnome/share/mime`, `/usr/share/mime` fixed this problem.

As was mentioned by Firelord in a comment, the type that the `*.desktop` files were assigned following this operation was `application/x-desktop`. I suspect it is likely that manually setting this as their mime-type would be sufficient to solve the problem.

For those who later see this post, in case it is helpful:

In related (to the solution, but not to the original question) news, this also takes me a step closer to making `rekonq` download files.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, but repeated use of `update-mime-database` did not work around the execution problem in my case. Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/894380/25036 under _*.desktop files opening in Kate_